# Counting events grouped by minutes on Pandas Time series

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I have a time series and I would like to count how many events per minute that I have in the dataframe. Then I would like to group all the dates together and print the datetime with events. Finally I would like to output a line graph and histogram using both bokeh and matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#alows you to see matplotlib in Inotepad
%matplotlib inline
dframe = pd.read_table('info.txt', sep=",", header = None)
```

I am importing a text file into Juypter and the dataframe is called dframe. The row is called datetime. I am using Juypter, pandas, numpy, bokeh, or matplotlib

```
dframe
<id>     <datetime>
0        20151227 06:51:30.218944
1        20151227 06:51:36.913871
2        20151227 06:51:37.198875
3        20151227 06:51:37.574203
4        20151227 06:51:37.286483
5        20151227 06:51:37.635841
6        20151227 06:51:38.070152
7        20151227 06:51:38.255787
8        20151227 06:51:38.188735
9        20151227 06:51:38.255831
10       20151227 06:51:38.255877
11       20151227 06:51:38.255920
12       20151227 06:51:38.893147
13       20151227 06:51:38.686167
```

A Quick Example of the correct output would look like this output below, however I am unable to print the output because of the following error.

```
<datetime>                  event
20151227 06:51:30.218944  1
20151227 06:51:36.913871  2
20151227 06:51:37.198875  4
20151227 06:51:38.070152  8
```

When I resample data I receive the following error

```
dframe.datetime.resample('60Min', how=sum, base=30).plot()
plt.show()


TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex
```

how do I strip away the seconds and then group all the "datetimes" together and print datetimes with events Then plot on a line graph and histograph?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To complete this I just used SED to delete everything after the "." and then I used uniq to group and count. My line graph worked after I removed the seconds.